# Running index.php from command line & load balancer health checks

Tags: http

Cutting to the chase, on the command line within wordpress root folder:

`php index.php`

Should this always return a response?

I'm having a technical discussion with my sysadmin about this issue.
Our Load balancers are running a http health check on / - a recent release I submitted failed because the load balancers are not seeing a response from the wordpress servers they manage.

Despite this, the website still functions as expected, however, the sysadmins - reasonably - don't want the release to go out if the http health check fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since wordpress's execution logic relies on parameters filled by the php-apache connector (mod_php) running a php command line is not guarantied to produce the same results or any at all, all depending on your local settings.

In any case, you should not check if your server is functioning from the server itself as there other web servers and network layer that can fail and you will not check them that way.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm not checking from the server itself except as a 'test' that the sysadmin is trying. Your answer has backed up what I have been trying to explain to the sysadmin. The load balancer is checking the servers via a http health check.

Comment: @MattTrow Don't forget to accept this answer (check mark on the left) if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have some application-layer security going on (a plugin or something) it could be dropping any requests it finds weird (like from localhost), thus ending with lack of response.

It could be something completely different, but this is what comes to my mind first for your case.